# Linq query to get one row from each list of lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a List of objects that all have a non-unique tablename property associated with them, but I want to make a second list of the names themselves.

example data:

```
{
"TableName": "CodeTable1",
"ID": 7,
"Value": "7 ",
"CodeStatus": "A",
"SiteLocationID": null,
},
{
"TableName": "CodeTable2",
"ID": 6,
"Value": "string value example",
"CodeStatus": "A",
"SiteLocationID": 1,
},
{
"TableName": "CodeTable2",
"ID": 18,
"Value": "different value etc",
"CodeStatus": "A",
"SiteLocationID": 2,
}
```

Ultimately I want to populate a dropdownlist with the only 2 options being CodeTable1 and CodeTable2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try Select(c=> new { TName = c.TableName});

Comment: @Niklas that would neither compile nor give the required result.

Comment: @Jamiec it will compile , although I didn't see the part about the collection not having duplicates, will need to group the results, won't be hard to improvise:)

Comment: @Niklas yes, you corrected the typo. The list will not be distinct as requested in the question, and given in all the answers. And thats the point if you want to answer, answer. If you need to comment, comment.

Comment: As I said, I missed that and I apologize.

Comment: It works if I add distinct on the end, but I think the below answer is more fitting for what I was looking for. But thank you for your help, I was all around this and couldn't land on the right methods to call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want a select and a distinct

```
var items = myList.Select(x => x.TableName).Distinct();
```

Comment: This answer most closely fits what I need with the shortest code, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) to get only unique values from table names:

```
list.Select(x => x.TableName).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the list on `TableName` propperty and then project the key of each group :

```
var tableNames = list.GroupBy(x=.x.TableName)
                     .Select(g=>g.Key);
```

This will give you unique `TableName` list as result.